# Does DB2Connect pause while querying Active Directory?

Tags: c#, active-directory, db2

Our system uses DB2Connect to access data stored on a mainframe zOS DB2 system. Occasionally we see that DB2Access will pause for some seconds. Our system is a C# application, which runs on a windows server. We use this package to connect to DB2

https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.Data.DB2.Core/3.1.0.500

We managed capture this pause on a Wireshark trace
First, we see traffic flowing nicely to and from the DB2 system
[image]

Then DB2 traffic will then pause, and we see a lot of traffic to and from our AD
[image]

After some seconds, AD traffic stops and we see traffic to and from the DB2-system again
[image]

Comments have asked questions about the connection string. User is a shared user of all requests (an application user), connection string is build like this:

```
        var builder = new DB2ConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Server = db2FailoverStatusEnum == Db2FailoverStatusEnum.PrimaryNode ? PrimaryServer() : BackupServer(),
            Database = db2FailoverStatusEnum == Db2FailoverStatusEnum.PrimaryNode ? PrimaryDbName() : BackupDbName(),
            UserID = _db2Descriptor.Db2User,
            Password = PasswordReplacement,
            Authentication = "SERVER_ENCRYPT",
            ClientWorkstationName = Environment.MachineName,
            ClientApplicationName = ApplicationName(),
            ProgramId = ApplicationName().ToUpper(),
            ProgramName = ApplicationName().ToUpper(),
            Connect_Timeout = 20,
            ConnectionLifeTime = 1200,
            DisableCursorHold = true,
            MinPoolSize = 20,
            MaxPoolSize = 50,
            QueryTimeout = 30,
            StatementConcentrator = "Literals",
        };
```

Also our connection usage is pretty much by the book, I believe (not real production SQL). We use Dapper to help interpret results

```
    using var connection = GetConnection();
    var result = await connection.QueryAsync("select name, creator from sysibm.systables fetch first 10000 rows only");
```

Does anyone have experience with DB2Connect making queries to AD?

And is there a way to avoid that, as it delays our connection to DB2?

Comment: how is Db2- authentication configured (userid+password,  or certificate etc?) .  Does the c# app use a dedicated sharedauthid, or does each user of the app authenticate individually with Db2?

Comment: There is a shared user (application user) which is sent to DB2 with a password as part of the connection string

Comment: The database takes time to access the data. Pauses with large databases are expected.  If you do similar queries with Vendors tools do you see same delays?

Comment: A Db2-cli client may query AD to determine group membership for a user. You would need a CLI trace to verify what the nuget is doing, as the wireshark may not tell the real story.

Comment: The pause / delay is not when executing a query, but when opening a connection. Appearantly a connection is always closed, when delivered from the connection pool. I could be wrong, but it looks like the open will query AD, possibly for properties of the user running the service (i.e. not the DB2-user), but that is just a guess

Comment: You could edit your question to add details, such as which settings for connection pooling the code specifies in the connection string, the exact provider name and the connection class being used.

Comment: Is there a relationship between the symptom occurrence and the number of concurrently opened connections?  Careful monitoring would show it.  Some tuning of pool config might help. It's unclear why ConnectionLifeTime is so high (default is 60) at 1200 twenty minutes. For each new connection I would expect a lookup on active directory to determine group memberships for the authid.

Comment: @mao " For each new connection I would expect a lookup on active directory to determine group memberships for the authid." That is exactly our suspicion as well. Only we are seeing it at "Open". ie. also when a connection is reused from the pool. Could you elaborate on what Db2Connect needs to look up in AD? Any link to documentation? Thanks

Comment: Tracing (of AD) or the Db2 client should yield the details. At the least, as I mentioned previously, the group memberships for the authid might be sought from AD. You should open a ticket with IBM to help with troubleshooting this configuration question, in case there are ways to workaround.   This is not really a matter for stackoverflow as it is not about programming per se, but about configuration.